# How to deal with paths not accessible without VPN connection or certain environments in the pythonic way

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, filepath

I am currently trying to make my tool go to a certain path when clicking browse. Problem is this path is **only** accessible to us via VPN or in citrix environment. I tried using try and except to see if it goes to the exception if it can't reach the path but it just hangs up. How should I handle paths like this? Can I use simple if and else statements in this case to check if the path is accessible?

**Scenario:**

```
try:
  if browse is clicked:
    open("path")
except:
    open("fail safe path")
```

How do I keep my tool from hanging up trying to connect to the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer in os.path.isfile() for checking if a file exists and using try and except to avoid hanging up if path was unreachable.

Something like this:

```
if browse is clicked:
    try:
       open("path")
    except:
       open("other path")
```

or

```
if browse is clicked:
    if os.path.isfile("path") == True:
       open("path")
    else:
       open("other path")
```